# Change `window.location` in Constructor Will Still Render Component First Before Redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

A component needs to check cookie if it is authenticated the component gets rendered otherwise it redirects the page to an external URL using the code below. I change the URL inside component constructor method,

```
window.location = '/external-location'
```

However, the component will render first and then the page gets redirected to the external path. Is there a way to avoid the initial rendering of the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `state` use it!
We can render "Nothing" (`null`) to the `DOM` on the first `render` call.
In your constructor you can check your condition and store it in the `state` this will affect the first render of course.
Then on `componentDidMount` check if you need to redirect and update the `state` if needed.

Here are 2 examples with the same code, only the initial value of `shouldRedirect` is changed of course.

**Should render the page example:**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      shouldRender: false,
      shouldRedirect: false // check your coockie
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { shouldRedirect } = this.state;
    if (shouldRedirect) {
      window.location = "https://google.com/";
    } else {
      this.setState({ shouldRender: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { shouldRender } = this.state;
    return shouldRender && <h3>I'm rendered!</h3>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Should redirect example:**

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      shouldRender: false,
      shouldRedirect: true // check your coockie
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { shouldRedirect } = this.state;
    if (shouldRedirect) {
      window.location = "https://google.com/";
    } else {
      this.setState({ shouldRender: true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { shouldRender } = this.state;
    return shouldRender && <h3>I'm rendered!</h3>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `throw (window.location = '/401or403')` in component constructor

Comment: Is this another hack?

Comment: It seems that you want to totally skip 'render()' from component mount phase whereas the official doc does not mention a way to do so, so you may call it hack. By the way `window.location` is not blocking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `componetWillMount`. Then you can set a flag and check that flag to stop the component from rendering in the `render` function.

Comment: Is this the right way to go? Seems like a hack to me.

Comment: Stoping the component from rendering is commonly done in the `render` function. If you follow the container and presentational component pattern, this is exactly how the presentational component is stoped from mounting until the data is available. Checking if you need a redirect is better done in `componentWillMount` than the constructor, however, if you are going to use a flag it could be done in `componentDidMount` as well.

Comment: because in my case the logic is slightly more complex. The component gets rendered is actually not the component contains the redirection (external URL) code but another component which responsible for another in-app guard/check.

Comment: @squgeim you are wrong and misleading, you shouldn't use the `componentWillMount` instead of the `constructor`, it's the other way around.
read the react docs, its recommended to not use it and use the `constructor` instead: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: @Sag1v Since check for redirection was sync, the flag for whether not the component was rendered could be set in `componentWillMount`. The flag doesn't even need to be a state, again because the check is sync. There is some debate on where to use `constructor` or `componentWillMount`, but I agree with you on that.